# Jenkins selenium grid plugin creates excessive logging

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

selenium hub creates excessive amount of log messages in the $JENKINS_HOME/selenium.log on INFO level. Changing the log level to "OFF" or "Serve", after jenkins restart does not take effect. It still keeps logging INFO level logs to selenium.log

Answer (score 0):

sounds like [JENKINS-5637](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5637). However, that was fixed more than 2 years ago. Do you need to update your plugin?

Comment: No. I believe 2.3 is latest plugin which I'm using.